# How GCC define the filename of a dynamic library?

Tags: gcc, linker

I am recompiling a project that is not mine.

I have a binary version of the project, and I decided to hack it a bit, so I downloaded the source for the same version I have in binary, and tried recompiling it.

It works, EXCEPT one thing is bothering me: on Windows (but I saw questions about this also happening on Linux) my recompiled version wants libpng14-14.dll but the official binary wants libpng15-15.dll

I want to know why.

I saw some posts on Ubuntu forums about the Snex9x emulator with the same issue on Linux instead (some versions want libpng14.so and others libpng15.so)

So, how GCC defines what is the filename of the library that the compiled program will look for when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

For linux, man ld:

```
       The linker uses the following search paths to locate required shared libraries:

       1.  Any directories specified by -rpath-link options.

       2.  Any directories specified by -rpath options.  The difference between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories  specified
           by  -rpath options are included in the executable and used at runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at
           link time. Searching -rpath in this way is only supported by native linkers and cross linkers which have  been  configured
           with the --with-sysroot option.

       3.  On  an  ELF  system, if the -rpath and "rpath-link" options were not used, search the contents of the environment variable
           "LD_RUN_PATH". It is for the native linker only.

       4.  On SunOS, if the -rpath option was not used, search any directories specified using -L options.

       5.  For a native linker, the contents of the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".

       6.  For a native ELF linker, the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or "DT_RPATH"  of  a  shared  library  are  searched  for  shared
           libraries needed by it. The "DT_RPATH" entries are ignored if "DT_RUNPATH" entries exist.

       7.  The default directories, normally /lib and /usr/lib.

       8.  For a native linker on an ELF system, if the file /etc/ld.so.conf exists, the list of directories found in that file.

       If the required shared library is not found, the linker will issue a warning and continue with the link.
```